# Error in QtMultimedia compilation for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qtmultimedia

I am trying to play a video in raspberry pi with Qt. For raspi to support multimedia i did the below steps.

1. Used a precompiled qt 5.2.1 version in the sd card
2. Copied qt code for qtimageformats qtsvg qtxmlpatterns qtdeclarative qtgraphicaleffects qtmultimedia qtquick
3. Installed packages needed for multimedia as in link [building qt 5 on raspi](http://www.ics.com/blog/building-qt-5-raspberry-pi)
4. builded qtimageformats qtsvg qtxmlpatterns qtdeclarative
   qtgraphicaleffects qtmultimedia qtquick1

While building qtquick1 I get error :

../../inlcude/QtDeclarative/5.2.1/QtDeclarative/private/../../../../../src/declarative/qml/declarativedata_p.h: In static member function 'static void QDeclarativeData::init()':../../include/QtDeclarative/private/../../../../../src/declarative/qml/declarativedata_p.h:85:9: **error: 'destroyed_qml1' is not a member of QAbstractDeclarativeData'**
Makefile:14429: recipe for target '.obj/qdeclarativeparser.o' failed
make[2]: *** [.obj/qdeclarativeparser.o] Error 1

Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Your question is related to compilation of QtMultimedia, then you say you used a precompiled Qt, and finally you show a compilation error about QtQuick1. I think this question should be closed as off topic unless you specify what's the problem with QtMultimedia, and not another module. Also, there is little information about what you did, and how. This question cannot be answered without that vital information.